# Is there any way to calculate or estimate DPS?

Tags: diablo-ii

Coming back to the game after a long time, I see the damage range of weapons, and the fact that they have different attack speeds.  Based on my experience with other games, it is easier for me to compare how good weapons are based on damage per second (DPS).  Some simple assumption, like that I have 100% hit rate is fine with me if that makes it easier.  After looking around a little I can't find an easy way to compare damage/speed between multiple weapons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There are a number of damage calculators out there. [This](http://diablo.incgamers.com/calcs/) covers both the damage side and attack speed sides of the coin at once.

Alternatively, for more complex questions, such as factoring in werewolf attack speed, Zeal, Jab etc, I refer you to [This](http://www.theamazonbasin.com/d2/d2_tools_and_links.php)for a good list, if slightly dated.

The reference bible I used to use when playing D2 was [This](http://www.theamazonbasin.com/d2/forums/index.php?showtopic=36666).

For an more recent compilation, [This](http://www.mannm.org/d2library/faqtoids/faqtoids_eng.html) provides a reasonably thorough (at least as of 1.11) compendium.

I Hope that helps. There is so much good information out there on D2, as it has been around so long and was so popular, that I didn't think it constructive to reinvent the wheel and write down formulae here :)

Comment: HtH? what does that mean?

Comment: hope that helps

Comment: It might be a good idea to quote some of the text/formulae from the linked articles to preserve this answer. If those sites or links go away (however unlikely) this answer becomes useless.

Comment: @Jasarien, I'm sorry but the damage mechanics in D2 are very complicated, with many special cases and variables, stemming partly from the 2-d frame-based nature of the game and partly from the diversity of combat types. I do not personally have the time to start with the fundamentals to derive some grand unified formulae. Even describing the mechanics would require a mini-essay. Sorry.

Comment: @Jasarien [third link](https://www.theamazonbasin.com/) is now, in fact, dead

Comment: Yup, 50% of the links in this answer are now unavailable. Exactly what I was talking about (...checks date...) 9 years ago.